# How to save bold font using html in objective c?

Tags: html, objective-c, iphone

I've typed some text in uitextview and also I've select some text and make it bold.After that I'm going to save this data into my application.Now,When I'm going to fetch that data then it will not displaying same as I've saved.

Its not save bold font.

Below is the code :

## pragma mark - btnActions

```
   -(IBAction)btnActions:(UIButton *)sender
        {
            [self addOrRemoveFontTraitWithName:@"Bold" andValue:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];

        }
```

## pragma mark - Private method implementation

```
-(void)addOrRemoveFontTraitWithName:(NSString *)traitName andValue:(uint32_t)traitValue{
NSRange selectedRange = [txtViewNote selectedRange];

NSDictionary *currentAttributesDict = [txtViewNote.textStorage attributesAtIndex:selectedRange.location
                                                                  effectiveRange:nil];

UIFont *currentFont = [currentAttributesDict objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName];

UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [currentFont fontDescriptor];

NSString *fontNameAttribute = [[fontDescriptor fontAttributes] objectForKey:UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute];
UIFontDescriptor *changedFontDescriptor;

if ([fontNameAttribute rangeOfString:traitName].location == NSNotFound) {
    uint32_t existingTraitsWithNewTrait = [fontDescriptor symbolicTraits] | traitValue;
    changedFontDescriptor = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:existingTraitsWithNewTrait];
}
else{
    uint32_t existingTraitsWithoutTrait = [fontDescriptor symbolicTraits] & ~traitValue;
    changedFontDescriptor = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:existingTraitsWithoutTrait];
}

UIFont *updatedFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:changedFontDescriptor size:0.0];

NSDictionary *dict = @{NSFontAttributeName: updatedFont};

[txtViewNote.textStorage beginEditing];
[txtViewNote.textStorage setAttributes:dict range:selectedRange];
[txtViewNote.textStorage endEditing];
}
```

## pragma mark - btnSave

```
-(IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender
  {
            NSURL *documentDirectoryURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

            NSURL *documentURL = [documentDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.html"];


            NSString *htmlCode = txtViewNote.text;

            NSError* error;

            if (![htmlCode writeToURL:documentURL atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't save file because: %@", error);
            }

            NSString* fileToUpload = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:documentURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

            if (!fileToUpload) {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't read file because: %@", error);
            }


}
```

can any one html me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are saving the plain text of the textView instead of the attributedText.

> NSString *htmlCode = txtViewNote.text;

Instead you should save the attributed text like this:

> ```
> NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute, nil];
> NSData *htmlData = [[self txtViewNote].attributedText dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [self txtViewNote].attributedText.length) documentAttributes:attributes error:NULL];
> NSString *htmlCode = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
> ```

If you want to write the htmlCode to the textView, you should:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *tmp = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:htmlData options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
[txtViewNote setAttributedText:tmp];
```

Comment: sorry, the htmlData should be:
    NSData *htmlData = [txtViewNote.attributedText dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, txtViewNote.attributedText.length) documentAttributes:attributes error:NULL];

and the tmp should be:
NSMutableAttributedString *tmp = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:htmlData options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
[txtViewNote setAttributedText:tmp];

I will edit this in the post.